# Create node.js static html (or whatever) to edit files in package. Building a live Sass editor

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, static, sass

My goal is to build an editor for sass (scss) variables in a theme builder. But I keep finding that writing to files is restricted even though the file is not running on a server (or perhaps it should if local). Basically I want to serve up an html page that has a form to edit SCSS variables and then save those edits and then rerun the gulp stream to spit out the proper css.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that Electron is the tool that I need. I stumbled upon it after lots of searching. Pretty cool too! Lot's to learn and so little time!